# EIEIO (bzr, cedet 1.1) not loading in emacs, version 1.3 is already loaded

Tags: emacs, cedet

I downloaded and compiled the development branch of CEDET, and I load it according to the guide on the webpage, but when I start Emacs, i get

> error: EIEIO Version 1.3 already loaded; load CEDET at the beginning of your init file to avoid this.

This is literally the first lines of my .emacs in ~/.emacs:

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/cedet/common/cedet.el")
(semantic-load-enable-excessive-code-helpers)

(global-ede-mode t)

(require 'semantic-ia)
(require 'semantic-gcc)
(require 'semanticdb)
```

I seriously don't see what is wrong. I am also an Emacs newbie :P thanks for the help.
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO the error is self descriptive. Place your snippet at the begining of `.emacs`

Actualy Loading developement version is little different. Here is my relevent parts of my .emacs file. (change path of the cedet accordingly)

```
(unless (featurep 'cedet)
  (when (file-directory-p "~/.emacs.d/el-get/cedet")
    (progn
      (add-to-list 'load-path  "~/.emacs.d/el-get/cedet")
      (load-file "~/.emacs.d/el-get/cedet/cedet-devel-load.el"))))

;;; ede
(setq semantic-default-submodes
      '(;; cache(?)
        global-semanticdb-minor-mode

        global-semantic-highlight-edits-mode
        global-semantic-idle-local-symbol-highlight-mode
        ;; global-cedet-m3-minor-mode

        ;; code helpers
        global-semantic-idle-scheduler-mode
        global-semantic-idle-summary-mode
        global-semantic-idle-completions-mode

        ;; eye candy
        global-semantic-decoration-mode
        global-semantic-highlight-func-mode
        global-semantic-highlight-edits-mode
        global-semantic-stickyfunc-mode

        ;; debugging semantic itself
        ;;global-semantic-show-parser-state-mode 1   ;; show the parsing state in the mode line
        ;;global-semantic-show-unmatched-syntax-mode 1
        ))

(global-ede-mode 1)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but the thing is those lines are LITERALLY the first ones on the top of my .emacs

Comment: hmm.. how did you install emacs in the first place.? do you have any any packages installed in site-lisp that are causing eieio to load.?

Comment: I have a snapshot of emacs 24.1, I think CEDET is bundled with it already, apart from that, I have the emacs-goodies. How do I check who is loading eieio? It still shouldn't load before the first lines of .emacs, should it? /:

Comment: If I may advice, remove emacs-goodies, that's old and buggy, not so relevant to emacs24.1. By the way site lisp packages load automatically. you can check that with starting `emacs -Q` `emacs -q`

Comment: Thank you, I will try that and report back :)

Comment: Tried it with your setup, it loads, I also removed emacs-goodies (as in completely deleted). The version of eieio loaded is 1.3, I am confused. What was the problem before? What version did it want to load? Anyways, it seems to work now, so thanks.